# Есть код. Нужно его построчное объяснение

Tags: lisp

```
(defun task (lst1 lst2) 
(cond ((null lst1) nil) 
((member (car lst1) lst2) (task (cdr lst1) lst2)) 
(t (cons (car lst1) (task (cdr lst1) lst2)))))
```

Comment: Возможно, [связан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917552/Есть-код-на-lisp-Не-понимаю-что-делают-строки-Нужно-описание-кода-построчно)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний.

Comment: Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `task` - выводит те элементы `lst1`, которых нет в `lst2`.

#### Как это работает?

```
(defun task (lst1 lst2)                                    ; объявляется функция с двумя аргументами
    (cond                                                  ; проверяются условия
        ((null lst1) nil)                                  ; если lst1 пуст - вернуть пустой список
        ((member (car lst1) lst2) (task (cdr lst1) lst2))  ; если голова lst1 в списке lst2 - продолжить с остатком
        (t (cons (car lst1) (task (cdr lst1) lst2)))       ; в противном случае сохранить голову в результате.
    )
)
```